# SSRS Sharepoint List

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2007

How can I find out where a Sharepoint Report is getting its data from?

Is it possible/easy?

I have a live report similar to one I am about to produce (it will use the same data source) but I do not know where this is coming from!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by SharePoint Report. That could be a few things: maybe a .RDL (Reporting Services report) stored in SharePoint, but reporting on other data, or reporting on SharePoint lists/databases. Maybe an SSRS report using a third party plugin to report on SharePoint list data across multiple lists. Or even an Excel document linked to a Sharepoint list. Many possibilities. Can you share more about what sort of report you have, and what it might be using as its datasource? (I get that you don't know for certain, but right now I need more to go on.)

Comment: Open the .RDL file and look at the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to just copy and rename the file, upload it and edit it in Report Builder on SharePoint. This way you will maintain the exact data source without needing to edit XML.

If you want to download it, go here [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116)

However, if you favour a text editor you can open the .rdl file to edit it.
Look in the XML for something like:

```
    <DataSources>
    ..data source details here. 
    Where the data comes from
    </DataSources>
    <DataSets>
    .. actual returned date definitions here, like columns. 
    What the data is
    </DataSets>
```